# Well system cant keep up

Tags: well-pump

Hello I have a well system and cannot run my 2 hose bibs at the same time.  Also my sprinkler system only runs for about 2 mins before my pump runs to 0 pressure in the system.  I installed a new bladder tank last year and I just installed a new 40-60 pressure switch

Comment: Is this a change from past behavior?

Comment: Are you on a hill? Do you own property 30+ feet above your lawn area?

Comment: It is a fairly flat yard 3/4 acre

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: With the well pump not kicking in when the pressure drops ( or appears this way from your comment) you do want to get the system checked out.  There may be multiple things wrong but I have not seen a well go dry within 2 minutes and no recovery.  The pressure tank should be a good portion of that time and static level of the well is usually enough to pump for longer , an amp clamp meter can provide a clue on the current draw if the pump is running dry or possibly cracked pipes in the well because a torque arrestor was not used, a jet that is corroding and less efficient than normal may be it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are "pumping air" bc you pumped the well down below the pump. The well can't produce the volume you are trying to pull.  There are controls that can detect when you are "pumping air"...the amp draw of the pump is a lot less when pumping air than when pumping water. The control will shut off the pump for some period of time to allow the well to recover. The timings are adjustable to the hydrologics of the well.

Systems can be designed to have a holding tank (not a pressure tank) that can be slowly filled based on the production capacity of the well. Then a jet pump can get the water from the holding tank and pump it into a pressure tank.

Obviously this is a much more complex system that will need to be designed, but it's the best way to deal with a low producing well.

Comment: I don’t know that I would use a jet to pull from a cistern or holding tank because they are not very efficient but the other info is good.

Comment: Any centrifugal pump would do as long as the suction pipe isn't too long vertically.  Doesn't have to be a jet pump.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be exceeding the amount of water (or rate of water per unit time) that your pump (or well itself) can supply at once.

If this is a change from past behavior, it could reflect a pump degrading with age, or a change in the hydrology around the well.

- In the case of a degrading pump, there might be plenty of water in
  the well, but the pump can only pump it out so fast.
- In the case of a change in hydrology, the pump could be pumping out
  all the water in the well faster than the well refills from the
  ground around it.

Comment: When we put in a pool about 3 years ago we had to tear up the sprinkler system in the back of the house I noticed I could not run both hoses to fill the pool. Now I have put on a new PCb fornthe irrigation and can run the system for about 2 mins.  The pressure drops to 0 and by the time I turn of the sprinklers the pressure starts to go back up.  It sounds like maybe the pump no longer can handle the volume.  But why dosent the switch kick back on when pressure drops below 40

Answer (score 0):

You should call in a person or company that drills and services wells.

- The well may not have the capacity it used to due to mud and debris sealing the water entry to the well cavity.
- The existing pump impellers could be plugged with mud not allowing the pump to develop it's normal capacity and pressure.
- The pump may not have the capacity to do the job you want it to do.

Save yourself the aggravation of trying to guess what the problem is and "make the call" to an expert.